# Is there a way to remove punctuation at the start and end of each word in string but not the middle? Python

Tags: python, string, list, methods, punctuation

write a function beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation) which returns a new sentence (type string) that removes all the specified punctuations from words (words are separated by a white space).

For example, sentence "?hello !mango! and, ban,ana yum apple!" with punctuation "?!," would result in returning a string "hello mango and ban,ana yum apple".

Notice that "ban,ana" still contains comma.

Comment: Please share your work so we can guide you.

Comment: Use `split()` and `strip()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it for you.

```
from string import punctuation

a="""'?hello !mango! and, ban,ana yum apple!',  '?!,' """
new=[i.strip(punctuation) for i in a.split()]
print(" ".join(new))
```

output:

```
hello mango and ban,ana yum apple
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a good place to get started. Leaving the comma in banana is going to be a bit trickier. In the future, I suggest posting your attempt at the code, even if you think that it is rough. It is much easier to guide you in the right direction that way. Best of luck!

```
import string

def beautify_sentence(sentence, punctuation):
        beautiful = sentence.translate(str.maketrans('', '', string.punctuation))
        return beautiful

print(beautify_sentence('?hello !mango! and, ban,ana yum apple!',  '?!,'))
```